# Разрешить удаленное подключение mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

Вот настройки `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
bind-address=127.0.0.1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=root
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
long_query_time=0.2
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
innodb_file_per_table

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Дал права 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Пишет - подключение не установленно, так как удаленный комп отверг запрос на подключение.

ps `Iptables` вырубил с концами.

Comment: Непонятно, подключаетесь с другого компьютера? тогда надо исправить строку, например так `bind-address=0.0.0.0`